# Java application on Windows system running as USB peripheral

Tags: java, usb, libusb, peripherals

Is there a way to have a USB device act as a Host and an application on a Windows based system to act as the Peripheral?  We have a USB device that is the host and we need it to connect to our application running on a Windows based system.  The device is using USB 2.0 On-the-go specification, but it needs to run in Host role.  We have found a few libraries and what not but they seem to only work if the application is host and the device is the peripheral.  Any information or leads would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB Ports on a typical Windows PC can only talk in Host mode. This means that if your device is directly connected to a PC (including hubs), it **has** to run in device mode.

There are devices that can talk to 2 USB hosts at one (e.g. some USB<->USB PC connection cables). That could be one solution to your problem, but to me it looks more like you just have to adapt your devices software some bits.

Comment: That's what we were thinking, we're going to give the cable a shot and work our way down the line.

Comment: We are running into exact same problem. Did the cable work or did you find some other solution?

Comment: me too. did you find any solution ? @MattE